# Create new sheet from template sheet based on range in base sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

not sure why it is not making new sheets based on range (J1:J5)? It just duplicates "template".  Very new at this

```
function makeCopies() {
  //getting active spreadsheet
  var activeSreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //getting basic sheet
  var basicSheet = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("base");
  //getting active spreadsheet
  var activeSreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //getting template sheet
  var templateSheet = activeSreadsheet2.getSheetByName("template");  
  //setting template sheet as active
  activeSreadsheet2.setActiveSheet(templateSheet);
  //getting values from selected range
  var rangeArr = basicSheet.getRange("J1:J5").getValues();
  //going through range values
  for (i = 0; i < rangeArr.length; i++) {
    //preparing name for new sheet
    var name = (i + 2) + '. ' + rangeArr[i][0];
    //making duplicate of base sheet
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
    //setting new name for duplicated sheet
    if (name) {
      Logger.log("name" + rangeArr[i] + "already exists");
    } else {
      template.copyTo(ss).setName(rangeArr);
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it just duplicates 'template' "?

Comment: Perhaps you should add a tag for whatever 'SpreadsheetApp' is to get more attention for this question.

Comment: I want it to name the new copied sheet with what I have on the base sheet in column "J" with contents of template sheet.   It copies the contents of template sheet but names it Copy of template...copy of copy of template and so on.

Comment: I also want it to check and make sure that the new sheet doesn't already exist and if so skip making the new sheet .

Comment: You should study your code again - as written, you have told it to unconditionally duplicate the active sheet. You then never change the name of this sheet, and reference some undefined variables like `template` and `ss` as well. I recommend explaining, line-by-line, the purpose of your script to a nearby object, in order to help you conceptualize what is happening and whether or not certain lines are useful or not.